# Lp and lpr postscript printing behaviour

Tags: printing, cups, raspbian, postscript

I recently created a wireless print server with cups and samba on raspbian. I'm able to print from every device on my home network but I noticed a strange behaviour: when I print a postscript file directly from the raspberry pi lp works perfectly, while lpr prints a lot of sheets, the majority blank, some with random lines. Has someone experienced the same? Can someone give me or point me to a clear explanation about how gs, lp, lpr and cups interoperate?

Answer (score 2):

CUPS is the printing system under Linux. In particular, it provides a server and clients. The `lp` and `lpr` are two common commands to print files: `lpr` is the BSD one, and `lp` the System V one. There exist various implementations (more or less compatible with the original commands), but nowadays they should be CUPS clients. You should check that with `dlocate` or `dpkg -S`: if raspbian is like Debian, `lp` should be provided by `cups-client` and `lpr` should be provided by `cups-bsd` (both binary packages are from the `cups` source package). AFAIK, `gs` is unrelated on the client side.

Your problem is quite strange since `lp` and `lpr` should behave in the same way (if they are both the CUPS clients). To solve your problem, I suggest that you look at `strace` output to see if there are important differences. For instance, see what files under your home directory and under `/etc` are read.

Comment: I've had a related issue where `lp` recognizes a printer name and `lpr` doesn't.  So they are definitely not always the same.

Comment: @NormanRamsey They are different, but should behave in the same way (up to usage differences). In particular, the `THE DEFAULT DESTINATION` paragraph of their respective man pages is the same. Said otherwise, what you observed might be a bug. I suggest that you look at possible differences in `strace` output, as I said.